# how to handle multiple domains on one server?

Tags: url, redirect, directory, dns

Let's say I started out with one domain on a server called "www.oldsite.com". Then I decided to register another domain,"www.newsite.com" and put the new domain's files into the directory, "www.oldsite.com/newsite/". How do I allow the user to visit "www.newsite.com" and access the pages of the new site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for host header redirection.  This is configured differently for each web server, but the concept is the same.  When the HTTP request comes in, the web server checks the host name, and redirects to the correct application accordingly.

Host Headers in IIS7:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx

Virtual Hosts in Apache:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: is there a comprehensive tutorial for editing the .htaccess file?

Comment: I don't think you're really supposed to use .htaccess unless you have to - in the past I've used httpd.conf to set this kind of thing up.  But here you go:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: bah, I'm still very new to this. Do I have to use IIS7 to create a httpd.conf file? Can I just create a httpd.conf in the root directory  and add the code with the <VirtualHost> tags and what not?